# cx_freeze: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copyDependentFiles'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an executable for a Python script using Flask. For some reason when I am trying to generate the executable I am getting the following error:

> C:\Users\jcalv\Downloads\Cache>python setup.py build Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 12, in 
>       icon="incap.ico" TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copyDependentFiles'

This are the contents of my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_files = [ 'templates/']

packages = [ 'jinja2', 'jinja2.ext']
flaskapp = Executable(script="incap.py",
                      base="Win32GUI",
                      targetName="incap_cache.exe",
                      copyDependentFiles=True,
                      icon="incap.ico"                      
                  )
setup(
    name="Cache_Purger",
    version="1.0",
    author="J",
    description="Flask web app that allows...",
    options={
        'build_exe': {
            'include_files': include_files,
            'includes': packages,
            'build_exe': "build"
        }
    },
    executables=[flaskapp]
)
```

I am currently using Python 3.6.5 and cx-freeze-5.1.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cx_freeze version 5.0 the setting `copyDependentFiles` has been removed from the `Executable` class.

You can read about this (and delve into the pull requests that detail it in the [release notes](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-5-0-november-2016)) as well as other changes in that and more recent versions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I removed 'copyDependentFiles=True' from my setup.py as it is no longer required since if you have 'include_files' option it will "implicitely" copy the dependent files.